# Using Nanodrop for UV/Vis analysis of compounds at limited amounts

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, solvents, spectrophotometry

I am no chemist, but a biologist who knows some biochemistry. I have some natural extracts at limited quantity, which I have been evaluating using mainly GC-MS. These extracts are rich in liquid alkaloids.

I was wondering whether a trivial "Nanodrop" could help me in some analyses  -- e.g. estimating concentration of some main compound --, via UV/Vis absorbance scans. A typical nanodrop can scan for absorbance within the range 200-800 nm.

Usually molecular biologists are the only ones routinely making use of Nanodrop, strictly for DNA/RNA purity and quantitative estimations.

Has anyone here ever tried making use of a Nanodrop micro-spectrophotometre for general analytical purposes with other compounds?

[UPDATE]

I cannot add an answer as others for some reason closed it as "too broad". It isn't, see below.

---

After completing my tests, I have decided to come back to answer my own question.

A Nanodrop machine has served my purpose quite efficiently, as far as I can judge. I used have used it to evaluate the degree of purity of a natural alkaloid extract from insects, using synthetic alkaloid analogues as controls. See our published paper discussing the method [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.toxicon.2018.02.050), along with [raw data](http://dx.doi.org/10.17632/cpnscw2gkc.1).

We have noticed no alterations nor cross-contaminations to other DNA/RNA samples running in parallel, highlighting on the fact that the equipment was properly cleaned between each use (with 100% ethanol & distilled water).

Therefore, yes: I recommend using the Nanodrop as a cheap & quick method to scan alternative biological/chemical samples, provided the chemicals and solvents involved are compatible with the pedestal according with the manual.

Hope this discussion encourage others to *dare* into multidisciplinary research!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but I suspect this isn't quite the right forum for this question. A literature search would likely yield more fruitful results than waiting for a random analytical chemist who happens to have some expertise here.

Comment: Perhaps not the "right forum" because I said I am no chemist? Sorry to intrude. I don't think many chemists are in touch with biologists and their Nanodrops, based on the literature and my peers...

Comment: You didn't interpret what I said the way I wanted you to. Doesn't matter if you're a chemist or not. This isn't the right forum because you're sitting around _waiting_ for the right chemist to come along. Not just any chemist (as you pointed out) but someone knowledgeable on what sounds like something quite esoteric. I have a Ph.D. from MIT, but I know _nothing_ about this topic. I would do a literature search if I could, but at that point, it's easier just for you to do it yourself.

Comment: Could you tell us what a nanodrop is?

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon it is a micro-spetrophotometre for nanoliter-scale volumes. You apply a 0.5-2.0 ul droplet onto a pedestal and read out absorbance, fluorescence, transmittance, etc, data. It was released some 20 years ago and quickly got very popular among molecular biologists for (quickly) estimating DNA & RNA purity and concentrations. Possibly as a side-effect nowadays my colleagues seem to believe that it is only fit for that purpose. I'd surprised if no-one else uses it for general analytical purposes.

Comment: We got the Nanodrop One-C in our lab. We use it for example for quick determination of tetrazine concentration (strong absorbance at 535nm) or other dyes. It works well with water or DMSO but it's not very accurate in some cases. But if you don't care about some % up or down it does the trick.

Comment: I think this is a great question.  Thanks for posting it!

Comment: @DSVA You seem to be experienced with the technique. Can you please add your comments as an answer and elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: **Now** a literature search is possible into this experimental idea as suggested. Please feel free to peruse the cited literature in the question update. Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, i would say that you cant use Nanodrop for such work. Here is why:

From a quick google search it appears that a nanodrop is a UV-Vis spectrometer that can measure very small amounts of liquid. Looks like that  bio-sciences people (I am not a biologist or biochemist) use it to quantify nucleic acids by knowing the approximate molar absorptivity for DNA, RNA etc. at a specific wavelenth, measuring the sample's absorption at that wavelength, and applying the Beer-Lambert law assuming that the only compounds that absorb in the wavelenght that measurement takes place in their sample are the nucleic acids (which i guess is a fair assumption for such samples).

However, I am not sure from your question if you want to measure nucleic acid content in a sample also containing alkaloids as part of the sample matrix or you want to quantify the various alkaloids in your sample.

I think you must mean the latter since you mention GC-MS in which case the nanodrop seems to be a poor choice: UV-Vis spectroscopy in general is a technique with very low resolution in terms of compound separation due to the broadness of the peaks in the absorption spectra. If you had only a few alkaloids in your mixture (which i dont think you do) maybe you could use nanodrop or a normal UV-Vis spectrometer followed by a lot of calibration and absorption band decomvolution in order to identify and quantify each component. If on the other hand you have a complex mixture (which is usually the case with natural extracts) any kind of UV-Vis spectroscopy will fall short. Even NMR spectroscopy which has a much higher resolution would struggle.

This is why GC-MS seems to be the best way for such work: the GC separates the mixture in simpler mixtures (or in the pure compounds if your sample is not too complicated) and then the MS identifies and quantifies the compounds present in each fraction. So i think that you will either need to find more sample or further optimize your GC-MS method to increase sensitivity.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The part about the Nanodrop is not quite correct. We got the nanodrop One-C (drop and cuvette) which can measure every wavelength between 200 and 800nm, also full spectra and even time resolved.

Comment: Ok, the model i looked up was setup with certain wavelenths only. I should have thought that there would be more advanced versions of it! I ll edit accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: **Now** we're talking. Thanks for your insights, though still I haven't found someone who's experimented with that. I still see the application of a Nanodrop towards my alkaloids as in the same situation of nucleotide analyses of molecular biologists. Both are natural extracts. I'd emphasise that when molecular biologists assume the only compounds absorbing in a wavelength in their sample the nucleic acids, they are usually not right. For most DNA extracts there are intrinsic and added contaminants. Likewise their molecules have many analogues like mine; I'd like to estimate [] and purity.

Comment: @DSVA Not only models, but there are clear "opensource" instructions on how to make fully functional "Nanodrops". For instance: <http://hackteria.org/wiki/DIY_NanoDrop>  Ultimately I'd like to have one of those, 100% mine. First I want to make sure the effort is worth it.

Comment: You are trying to estimate how much alkaloids you have in total in your extract or which ones and in what amount of each?

Comment: AMM is absolutely right here, @Scientist: UV-Vis is a terrible technique when you have a complex mixture. There's no way you'd be able to speciate a natural extract, and the complex mixture means you have no ability to even guess at a reasonable molar absorption coefficient for the mixture. AMM's suggestion of a chromatography method hyphenated with mass spec is likely your best bet.  **However**, your sample size may be too small for a realistic analysis.  You've posed a terrifically challenging analytical problem here.

Comment: @hBy2Py Yes I see the point, and thanks for bringing up further insights for me to consider. I however have a natural extract which is made of >95% w/w mixture of analogues of the same compound. I expect (haven't tested all yet) that all of them have the same or very approximately same peak absorbance wavelength. I believe the method is very practical, and will test it further.